# DRF serializer to group data by attributes into arrays

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I would like to create a Django Rest Framework serializer which can group my data based on attributes of each object.

My models are described as follows:

```
class Courses(models.Model):
    coursenum = models.AutoField(db_column='courseNum', primary_key=True)
    coursecode = models.CharField(db_column='courseCode', max_length=10, blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'courses'


class Sections(models.Model):
    sectionnum = models.AutoField(db_column='sectionNum', primary_key=True)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=False)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sections'

class Teachers(models.Model):
    teachernum = models.AutoField(db_column='teacherNum', primary_key=True)
    teachername = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'teachers'


class Timeslots(models.Model):
    timeslotnum = models.AutoField(db_column='timeSlotNum', primary_key=True)
    starttime = models.TimeField(db_column='startTime', blank=True, null=False)
    endtime = models.TimeField(db_column='endTime', blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'timeslots'


class Venues(models.Model):
    venuenum = models.AutoField(db_column='venueNum', primary_key=True)
    venuename = models.CharField(db_column='venueName', max_length=6, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'venues'


class Slots(models.Model):
    daynum = models.IntegerField(db_column='dayNum', primary_key=True)
    venuenum = models.ForeignKey(Venues, models.CASCADE, db_column='venueNum')
    timeslot = models.ForeignKey(Timeslots, models.CASCADE, db_column='timeSlot')
    coursenum = models.ForeignKey(Courses, models.CASCADE, db_column='courseNum', blank=True, null=True)
    teachernum = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, models.CASCADE, db_column='teacherNum', blank=True, null=True)
    sectionnum = models.ForeignKey(Sections, models.CASCADE, db_column='sectionNum', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'slots'
        unique_together = (('daynum', 'venuenum', 'timeslot'),)
```

Using a simple Model serializer with nested sibling serializer calls, I can get the data as following:

```
"slots": [
        {
            "daynum": 1,
            "venue": {
                "venuenum": 2,
                "venuename": "FF-105"
            },
            "timeslot": {
                "timeslotnum": 2,
                "starttime": "09:30:00",
                "endtime": "10:20:00"
            },
            "course": null,
            "teacher": null,
            "section": null
        },
        {
            "daynum": 1,
            "venue": {
                "venuenum": 2,
                "venuename": "FF-105"
            },
            "timeslot": {
                "timeslotnum": 3,
                "starttime": "10:30:00",
                "endtime": "11:20:00"
            },
            "course": {
                "coursenum": 1,
                "coursecode": "CS 2002"
            },
            "teacher": {
                "teachernum": 1,
                "teachername": "TEHNIAT MIRZA"
            },
            "section": {
                "sectionnum": 1,
                "semester": "3",
                "section": "B"
            }
        },
]
```

However, I want to iterate over these results in a React table and want to sort them and group them according to each object's attribute so that it's easy to show:

***Desired output***

```
"slots": [
    '1': //the day number
        [
            'FF-104': []
            'FF-105': [
                    {
                        "daynum": 1,
                        "venue": {
                            "venuenum": 2,
                            "venuename": "FF-105"
                        },
                        "timeslot": {
                            "timeslotnum": 2,
                            "starttime": "09:30:00",
                            "endtime": "10:20:00"
                        },
                        "course": null,
                        "teacher": null,
                        "section": null
                    },
                    {
                        "daynum": 1,
                        "venue": {
                            "venuenum": 2,
                            "venuename": "FF-105"
                        },
                        "timeslot": {
                            "timeslotnum": 3,
                            "starttime": "10:30:00",
                            "endtime": "11:20:00"
                        },
                        "course": {
                            "coursenum": 1,
                            "coursecode": "CS 2002"
                        },
                        "teacher": {
                            "teachernum": 1,
                            "teachername": "TEHNIAT MIRZA"
                        },
                        "section": {
                            "sectionnum": 1,
                            "semester": "3",
                            "section": "B"
                        }
                    },
            ]
        ]
]1
```

*To summarize, what I want to do is*
On first level, group the results by daynum attribute
On second level, group the results by venuenames(or nums whatever works), while also sorting by the timeslots.

Comment: Serializers don't really have logic, so you can't do this.  You are going to need a custom query to your database at best, or to roll your own in python code.  You could also just do it in React :)  Have you considered naming your models in python standard, and using https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case to convert to camelCase afterwards?

Comment: @AndrewBacker thanks a lot! I wrote a custom query and answer is below

Answer (score 0):

So from my findings, Django Rest Framework serializers don't work that way and as @Andrew Backer pointed out, I might have to use a custom query to retrieve the data accordingly.

I originally looked into `itertools.groupby` but it wasn't as intuitive to me, so I resided with writing a custom query.

How the query worked:

Retrieve all Slot objects, but order them like: 
`Slots.objects.all().order_by('daynum','venuenum__venuename','timeslot')`

Using a nested `collections.defaultdict`, i.e:
`data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`

For each `daynum`, add a list for `venuenum__venuename` and append Slot objects accordingly

Code:

```
class TimetableGenerateView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
        slots = Slots.objects.all().order_by('daynum','venuenum__venuename','timeslot')
        for slot in slots:
            data[slot.daynum][slot.venuenum.venuename].append(SlotSerializer(slot).data)
        return Response(data)
```